# How to create ajax conditional confirmation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I make :confirm=>"Are you sure" conditional?
I have this code

```
<div id="container"><%= form_for @question,:remote=>true,:html=>{:name=>"question"} do |f|%>
    <p>
        <div class ="row">
        <%= label_tag(:topic,@displayquestion.question_text,:class=>"form-label")%>
        </div>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>
    <%= f.radio_button(:answer, "1") %>
    <%= label_tag(:choice1,@displayquestion.choice1,:class=>"form-label")%>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>
    <%= f.radio_button(:answer, "2") %>
    <%= label_tag(:choice2,@displayquestion.choice2,:class=>"form-label")%>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>
    <%= f.radio_button(:answer, "3") %>
    <%= label_tag(:choice3,@displayquestion.choice3,:class=>"form-label")%>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>
    <%= f.radio_button(:answer, "4") %>
    <%= label_tag(:choice4,@displayquestion.choice4,:class=>"form-label")%>
    </label>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit(:value=>next,:class =>"button",:disable_with=>'loading') %>
<% end %></div>
```

I want to make it such that it will prompt only if no radio button is selected.
I have this jQuery code which will prompt the user if no radio button was selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#container").on("click", ".edit_question", function(event){

     if (!$("input[@name='question[answer]']:checked").val()) {
       confirm('Are sure you want to submit a blank answer?');
    }

   if (!$("input[@name='answer[]']:checked").val()) {
       confirm('Are sure you want to submit a blank answer?');
    }

}
);
});
```

The problem is that even when I click cancel, the ajax request is sent, how do intercept the ajax request to call the jQuery code?

Thanks for the pointer!
I did it this way and it works!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#container").on("submit", ".edit_question", function(event){
    var reply = true;
     if (!$("input[@name='question[answer]']:checked").val()) {
       reply=confirm('Are sure you want to submit a blank answer?');
    }

   if (!$("input[@name='answer[]']:checked").val()) {
       reply=confirm('Are sure you want to submit a blank answer?');
    }
   return reply;
}
);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click function needs to return false to cancel the page submission. confirm() returns a bool, true for ok, false for cancel.

Example:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".edit_question", function(event){

    if (!$("input[@name='question[answer]']:checked").val()
        || !$("input[@name='answer[]']:checked").val()  ) {
        return confirm('Are sure you want to submit a blank answer?');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yours is shorter and nicer, will use yours. Thanks!